# Disabling Insertion or Remove empty row in SlickGrid

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I was having a requirement to have an editable grid and for that I am using SlickGrid. SlickGrid also provide facility to insert a new row but I only want it for editing available records and no new records are to be inserted. Is there any listener or attribute in SlickGrid to disable the insertion or which can remove the last empty row from the grid?

Answer (score 0):

If you are editing records, the values should be edited in place or via a [composite editor](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-composite-editor-item-details.html). Editing in place is enabled by providing a custom editor or specifying one of the [existing editors](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.editors.js) within the column definition for the [editor property](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Column-Options).

The ability to insert a new row is controlled by the configuration property [`enableAddRow`](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Grid-Options) which is false by default. If you have enabled that ability, simply remove it from your config object.